# Getting text values from dynamically created Qline edits in Qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, dynamic, gettext, qlineedit

I have created a set of `QlineEdits` successfully and assigned each `LineEdit` an Object name but unfortunately when I try to read and get them into a `QStringList` I get an error stating:

```
"Textbox was not declared in this scope"
```

my code is as follows:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
   f1 = new QFrame();
   f2 = new QFrame();
   f3 = new QFrame();

  a= new QLabel(f1);
  b=new QLineEdit(f2);
  c=new QLineEdit(f3);

    QString oName= QString::number(i);
    b->setObjectName("Textbox"+oName);

    ui->verticalLayout->addWidget(f1);
    ui->verticalLayout_2->addWidget(f2);
    ui->verticalLayout_3->addWidget(f3);

    a->setText(newList[i]);

}
```

and from the button click event I won't to get each text in the dynamically created `QLineEdits`!

```
void NewOrders::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

 for(int i=0;i<getList.size();i++){
       QString oName= QString::number(i);
     getList<<(ui->("Textbox"+oName)->text());
 }
}
```

Here `getlist` and `newlist` are `QStirngLists` are already defined as public!
How can I correct this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the object through the `objectName` you must use the [`findChild`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#findChild)

```
void NewOrders::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
      QLineEdit *le = findChild<QLineEdit*>(QString("Textbox%1").arg(i));
      if(le){
          getList<<le->text();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is "w" in the if statement?

Comment: @KasunKarunarathna it was a mistake, update my answer

Comment: thanx nate I'll try this and see!